# Declarar valor da variável na chamada da função

Tags: javascript, funções

Não sei como chamar isso para procurar no Google ou se é possível fazer isso. Eu tenho um objeto que está da seguinte forma:

```
var clear = {
    Search_r: false,
    Search_f: false,
    Search_e: false
}
```

E tenho a seguinte função

```
function clearSearch(clear) {
    if(clear.Search_r) {
        $(".search-r").html("")
    }
    if(clear.Search_f) {
        $(".search-f").html("")
    }
    if(clear.Search_e) {
        $(".search-e").html("")
    }
}
```

Chamo a função assim

```
    clear.Search_r = true
    clearSearch(clear)
```

Funciona muito bem, porém eu queria saber como se faz para passar o `true` dentro da chamada da função e não na linha de cima. Algo como:

```
clearSearch(clear.Search_r = true) //isso não funciona e nem da erro
```

Ou seja, não funciona, da **undefined**. Como seria o correto e se possível, como se escreveria isso no Google para achar outras soluções?

Comment: Qual sua intenção de fazer isso(passar o valor para variavel dentro da chamada)? sendo que do primeiro jeito está funcionando.

Comment: *"eu tenho uma variável do tipo array que é a seguinte"*, o seu exemplo **não é um array**, é um objeto, seria um array se fosse assim, por exemplo: `var clear = [ { ...}, {....} ];`

Comment: @sant0will usar 1 linha no lugar de duas e aprender como se faz isso para algo mais complexo

Comment: @RicardoPontual legal, obrigado

Comment: `clearSearch(clear.Search_r = true)` essa sintaxe funciona em algumas linguagens, mas infelizmente no `javascript` não :(  você tem de passar o objeto com uma propriedade booleana dentro (ex: `var parm = { Search_r = true }; clearSearch(param)`, ou do jeito mais simples: `clearSearch(true)`

Comment: @RicardoPontual é que eu queria de fato utilizar o menor número de linhas possíveis, neste seu exemplo ainda utilizaria 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que a sua função está escrita, a passagem de parâmetro que você deseja se dá dessa forma:

```
clearSearch({ Search_r: true })
```

Comment: perfeição, funcionou incrivelmente, neste caso é passar parâmetro em chamada de função? e só funciona por eu ter um objeto?

Answer (score 3):

Como você está utilizando apenas um parâmetro do Objeto, não é necessário passá-lo por completo, basta passar `true` ou `false` para a função, por exemplo:

```js
function clearSearch(clear = true) {
  if (clear) {
    console.log("Limpa o console")
  } else {
    console.log("Ops")
  }
}

clearSearch(true)
clearSearch(false)
clearSearch()
```

Caso seja necessário passar o Objeto, ao invés de fazer `funcao(obj.clear = true)`, basta utilizar

```js
function clearSearch(obj = {field1: true, field2: false}) {
    if(obj.field1) {
        console.log("Limpa o campo 1")
    } else {
      console.log("Ops 1")
    }
    
    if(obj.field2) {
        console.log("Limpa o campo 2")
    } else {
      console.log("Ops 2")
    }
}

clearSearch({field1:true,field2:true})
clearSearch({field2:false,field2:false})

clearSearch({field1:true,field2:false})
clearSearch({field2:false,field2:true})

clearSearch()
```

Além das opções acima, você também pode usar a função `Object.assign`. Com essa função você pode definir os valores padrão do objeto.

```js
function clearSearch(obj) {
    obj = Object.assign({clear: true}, obj)

    if(obj.clear) {
        console.log("Limpa o console")
    } else {
      console.log("Ops")
    }
}

clearSearch({clear:true})
clearSearch({clear:false})

clearSearch()
clearSearch(false)
```

> Obs.: O valor que você está tentando passar é um Objeto e não um Array

Comment: eu quero usar em várias opções de if, Search_r, Search_f

Comment: @flourigh Então você pode usar conforme o segundo exemplo. Como seu código de exemplo é simples, baseei-me nele.

Comment: muito bom, amei a função, irei melhorar muito a minha com a ajuda da sua, isso seria objeto e passagem de parâmetro em chamada de função para procurar n google a aperfeiçoar?

Comment: @flourigh Não há um termo específico para isso, nos meus exemplos usei "valores padrão"

Comment: entendi, mas ficou bem legal mesmo, irei implementar no meu, agradeço demais

Comment: gostei da opção 3 que é a assign, ela funcionaria como na 2? com mais de um "Field"?

Comment: @flourigh é possível usar quantos campos quiser em ambos casos.